# Texture showing in preview render, but not in finished render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, materials, uv

I added a plane, UV-unwrapped it, and added a Checkerboard image texture. It shows perfectly fine in the render preview, but when I render it, it doesn't show /:

I checked the nodes, etc. I'm using Blender Cycles (:

[image]

Comment: Hello, welcome to BSE, adding more details will help you get more accurate answers, are you using BI, Cycles..? Attaching your .blend file and attaching images will even be better.

Comment: hey (: Thank you for your time! What's the best way to upload my .blend file?

Comment: You can upload your .blend here http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Could you look at my .blend-file? (:

Answer (score 1):

you have hidden some objects from the viewport but not from the render

change from this
[image]
to this
[image]

Comment: can you add settings for blender internal as well as part of your answer?.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: Could you look at my .blend-file? (:

Comment: I edited my answer , see if this works